# MockMVC ignorting order annotation and alphabetical method order working strangely

Tags: spring, mockito, junit5, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

`MockMVC` is ignoring order of `@Order` annotation, by the way, naming them in alphabetical order, when second method is named `test2_b`, the method become second do be executed as it should be, but in this case, renamed to `test2` it was the last one to be executed even though it should be the second one to be executed:

```
package com.javainuse.boot3security.test;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import com.javainuse.boot3security.repository.DadosPessoaisRepository;

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class ClassTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private DadosPessoaisRepository dadosPessoaisRepository;

    @Order(1)
    @Test
    public void test1_a() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Test1");    
    }

    @Order(2)
    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Test2");        
    }

    @Order(3)
    @Test
    public void test3_c() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Test3");        
    }   
    

    @Order(4)
    @Test
    public void test4_d() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Test4");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Test1
Test3
Test4
Test2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test method execution order is nothing to do with `@MockMVC`. It is controlled by the junit5 which by default is unpredictable. You have to annotate the test class with `@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)` if you want to control the execution order using `@Order`. Without it , `@Order` will not have any effect.

It is mentioned in the [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-execution-order-methods) as follows :

> To control the order in which test methods are executed, annotate your
> test class or test interface with `@TestMethodOrder` and specify the
> desired `MethodOrderer` implementation.

> - `MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation`: sorts test methods numerically based on
>   values specified via the `@Order` annotation

Answer (score 1):

Just the @Order annotation on the test methods will not work. You have to annotate the Test class with a specific TestMethodOrder:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class ClassTest {

    @Order(1)
    @Test
    public void test1_a() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Test1");    
    }

}
```

But please keep in mind, that enforcing a test order is not a good practice.

Comment: What is the good practice for testing a crud por example? (Create before update)

Comment: Every test should be self-contained and independent from other tests. So a "read test" should not depend on a previous "create test". The best thing would be to prepare an initial data set that is loaded with a @BeforeEach initializer.